# How to create single check box event for all check boxes in android?

Tags: android

I'm new to android it is possible in .net, But i want to build this logic in android is it possible to do that please help me, i know only creating check box event for each check box instead of that i want to create single event for all Check boxes please help me.

**Vb.net**

```
private sub Chkbox1_Checkchanged(byval sen as object,byval e as system.eventargs) handles Chkbox1.checked,chkbox2.checked,chkbox3.checked
    blnvalue=true
end sub
```

**android**

```
  chkbox1= (CheckBo1) findViewById(R.id.chkbox1);
  rbtn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
  {         
      public void onClick(View v) 
      {             
              blnvalue=true;
      }
   });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

implements  onCheckChangedEvent for for all checkBox.

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

        if (buttonView.getId() == activity.getCheckRefresh()) {
            activity.setRefreshRate("1");
            activity.setEnable(isChecked);
            return;
        }
}
```

Comment: what is activity is this object for what? please help me

Comment: Iam unable to access stack overflow how to activate this please help me

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are in an `Activity`, you can make your `Activity` implement `View.OnClickListener`, and then use `this` for each `View` within your `Activity`, even ones that aren't `CheckBox`.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    //declare checkboxes

    public void onCreate(Bundle something) {
        //setup stuff and get views

        rbtn1.setOnClickListner(this);
        rbtn2.setOnClickListner(this);
        rbtn3.setOnClickListner(this);
        rbtn4.setOnClickListner(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
       if(v == rbtn1) {
           //do stuff for checkbox1
       } else if(v == rbtn2) {
           //do stuff for checkbox2
       } else if(v == rbtn3) {
           //do stuff for checkbox3
       } else if(v == rbtn4) {
           //do stuff for checkbox4
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use onChackChanged Event & OnClickEvent for checkbox.

```
chkbox1= (CheckBo1) findViewById(R.id.chkbox1);
chkbox2= (CheckBo1) findViewById(R.id.chkbox2);


chkbox1.setOnClickListener(this);
chkbox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

chkbox2.setOnClickListener(this);
chkbox2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

public void onClick(View v) 
{
   if(v.getId() == R.id.chkbox2)
          // your code
}

public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

    if (buttonView.getId() == activity.getCheckRefresh()) {
        activity.setRefreshRate("1");
        activity.setEnable(isChecked);
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

u can do this.. here click is an inner class.. and create an instance of it n pass it to every setOnClickListener(click)

```
class click implements OnClickListener
{
 public void onClick(View v) 
{
// your code
}

}
```